# Quartz.net - Put assemblies (the individual schedules) in a different folder other then /bin

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net

I have a windows service calling quartz.net as follows:

```
  ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
  sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
  sched.Start();
```

My configuration file is a follows:

```
<add key="quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames" value="~/quartz/quartz_jobs.xml" />
```

On publishing my windows service I have devised the following folder structure:

```
/bin/      "Various Dlls for my windows service"
/bin/Quartz/    "Includes by schedule plugins ( Seperate classes and my Jobs file )
```

The problem I'm having, is that quartz doesn't find my assemblies unless I copy them into the root of /bin/.

Any ideas how I can keep all my schedule assemblies in a seperate folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Karell from Google groups.

Heres my code that addresses this question.

```
   AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
   currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);


 private Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {

            Assembly MyAssembly,objExecutingAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            AssemblyName[] arrReferencedAssmbNames = objExecutingAssemblies.GetReferencedAssemblies();
            if(args.Name.Contains("Coyname.Product.Service.Scheduler"))
            {
                string assName = Parser.ParseAssemblyNameReference(args.Name);
                var rootDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                var pluginDir = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, "Quartz");
                pluginDir += string.Format("\\{0}.dll",assName);;
                MyAssembly =  Assembly.LoadFrom(pluginDir); 
            }
            else
            {
                MyAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(string.Empty); 
            }
            return MyAssembly;
}
```